# Cosa significa "pazzo" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Lo studio del barone sembrava quello d'un sant'Agostino o un san Girolamo, confuso e divenuto un poco squinternato nell'affanno della ricerca della verità, ma anche la cella del monaco Fazello e insieme il laboratorio di Paracelso. Per tutte le pareti v'erano armadi colmi 
>   di libri nuovi e vecchi, codici, incunaboli, che da lì straripavano e invadevano, a pile e sparsi, la scrivania, le poltrone, il pavimento. Sopra gli armadi, con una zampa, due, sopra tasselli o rami, fissi 
>   nelle pose più bizzarre, occhio di **vetro pazzo**, uccelli impagliati di 
>   Sicilia, delle Eolie e di Malta.

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "vetro pazzo" in questo brano? Ho cercato alla voce "vetro" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato questa locuzione.

Oppure, come suggerito da @DaG, l'aggettivo "pazzo" non qualifica "vetro", ma invece "occhio"?

Answer (score 1):

Cercando il significato di [matto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/matto1/) (come sinonimo di pazzo) ho trovato:

> b. Falso, e perciò privo di valore: *orecchini di oro m.* (per un
>   diverso sign. di oro matto, v. matto3).

L'altro significato riportato per [matto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/matto3/) è:

> matto3 agg. [affine a matto1]. – **Opaco, non lucido. È voce dell’uso
>   ant., rimasta viva nell’espressione oro m.** (*Sul divano di scarlatto
>   ... Il bel capo sonnolento Forma un tono d’oro m., D’Annunzio*), e
>   ripresa modernamente nell’ottica (sull’esempio dell’ingl. *mat* o *matt*)
>   per indicare, in contrapp. *a lucido*, una superficie che diffonde la
>   luce anziché rifletterla: si dice, per es., di carta non lucida per la
>   stampa fotografica.

Quindi l'espressione vetro pazzo o vetro matto si riferisce al fatto che gli occhi degli uccelli impagliati erano costituiti da un vetro opaco, non lucido.

Comment: L'ipotesi sembra convincente ma, giusto per proporre un'alternativa, non potrebbe essere che “pazzo” si riferisca all'occhio? Cioè un occhio di vetro, con un aspetto folle (magari già solo perché è così sgranato, senza palpebre che battono, fisso).

Comment: In effetti non ci avevo pensato, potrebbe anche essere. Cercando occhio pazzo ho trovato [questo](https://www.funtasticshop.com/item_4848/Occhio-pazzo)

Comment: Questa spiegazione mi sembra un po' strana perché in catalano ("mat") e anche in castigliano ("mate") abbiamo aggettivi simili con lo stesso significato di quello riportato in questa risposta, ma che non hanno il significato di "pazzo". Tuttavia il Treccani afferma che questa voce è "affine a matto1", cioè al significato di "matto" come "pazzo", quindi non so veramente cosa pensare. Potrebbe anche ben essere giusto quello che spiega @DaG.